# Defining functions to return struct in C++

Tags: c++, function, struct

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct distance {
    int Kilometer;
    int Meter;
    int Centimeter;
};

distance add() {
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to define a function that returns a "distance" data type.
I'm getting hit with "distance is ambiguous" when trying to define the function.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't include `using namespace std;`.  See [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I get that std::distance exists, but I’m not sure I see how this would result in an ambiguity here. Is there a way to parse this code other than as a function returning a distance?

Comment: By using `using namespace std;`, you bring `std::distance` into the same scope as your `distance` struct. That is why your code is ambiguous - the compiler doesn't know which `distance` to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the struct name, define it in any namespace, or don't use `using namespace std;` because there is already a function called `distance()` in the `std` namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

namespace myNamespace{

    struct distance {
        int Kilometer;
        int Meter;
        int Centimeter;
    };

    distance add() {

        return distance();
    }
}

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    myNamespace::distance d1;
    d1 = myNamespace::add();

    return 0;
}
```

In general `using namespace std;` is bad practice, see 
[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/).

Answer (score 6):

As [@1202ProgramAlarm points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780148/defining-functions-to-return-struct-in-c#comment105704453_59780148), this is a classic reason why you should never include `using namespace std;`. Because you've introduced the `std` namespace, the compiler isn't sure what `distance` you mean: your custom `struct distance`, or `std::distance`, hence "distance is ambiguous".

The easiest and best fix is to not use `using namespace std`. Sure you might spend a few moments extra writing `std::` but you will save yourself from these headaches.

You could also rename your `struct` to be `Distance`, or you could qualify it with `::distance add()`